# Oracle Triggers, reliant on a key generated by a second trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have question about triggers. For my database assignment, I have to create a trigger that automatically generates an ID number, which I have done.
The problem is a second trigger needs to be made that also acts on the same data. Both are inserts. Since they have to be separate, I am not sure how to make this work.
From what I have been taught the way to make a trigger act on the most recent addition is to use:

```
WHERE ID=:NEW.ID;
```

where ID is the primary key, but this does not work for me when the ID is being generated by a trigger. Is there a method of creating a trigger that acts on the most recent row added to the table that does not reference the primary key?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? And can you share the table's structure? Also - why use two triggers? Why not just have one trigger that generates the ID and then uses it?

Comment: I need to use two triggers since the question requires each of the two triggers to have specific names. The RDBMS is oracle 11g. I can't share the structure, but what I need to do for the second trigger is to take data various non-ID columns and create a string to add to a description column.

Comment: Why do you need two triggers?

Comment: You could set a package variable in the first trigger and read it in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear why you need two triggers but let's assume it really makes sense (which I doubt).

Does the first trigger generates the ID from a sequence? In this case you can use value `CURRVAL` of the sequence. This pseudocolumn returns the current value of a sequence without increasing the value, see [Sequence Pseudocolumns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm)

If this does not fit your needs you can write a procedure which is then called be the trigger.

Would be like this:

```
create procedure PROC(aRow in ROWID) as
begin
...
end;

create first_trigger ....
begin
   ... whatever is needed at first trigger.
   PROC(NEW.ROWID);
end;


create second_trigger ....
begin
   ... whatever is needed at second trigger.
   PROC(NEW.ROWID);
end;
```

Both triggers would operate on the same row. You can also write current row values into a PL/SQL variable and process them by a Statement-Trigger (i.e. no row-level-trigger)

Comment: Thanks, the 2 triggers thing, was only necessary because it was specified in the assignment question.